# PrimeFaces confirm dialog is not returning true after clicking "OK"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I am using jsf PrimeFaces (v 6.1) library.

in my project there was a default javascript confirm dialog, smth. like:

```
if (!confirm('Sure?')) return false;
```

however I'm trying to use native confirmation dialog from PrimeFaces with no luck, smth. like:

```
if (!PF('confirmDlg').show()) return false;
```

What I need is make it simply return `true` after the user clicks **"Yes"** button in a dialog.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Why would you assume that `show` returns a boolean or any value? It doesn't. See the PF User Guide and the Showcase on how to use p:confirmDialog.

Comment: They note in their docs - confirm dialog is a graphic implementation of JavaScript confirm. Therefore I was expecting similar behavior. Any chance to get a solution instead of voting down my question? :)

Comment: The solution is to read the docs further then the first figurative introductory sentence :\